# What are values initialized to after calling Struct constructor?

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, initialization

I have a struct defined as:

```
typedef struct s non_t;

struct s {
 char tName; 
 int rCount; 
};
```

I then initialized it like this:

```
non_t *s = new non_t();
//s->tName = ??? 
//s->rCount = ???
```

So here, what do the values of `s->tName` and `s->rCount` get initialized to?? Are they `null` still? I want to copute something like:

```
s->rCount = s->rCount + 1
```

But in order for that to work properly I need `s->rCount` to be initialized to 0... I guess I'm just confused on how `struct` initialization really works?

Comment: What is the value of `???` in the `s->tName = ???` statement?

Comment: @Liturgist Sorry if my question was misleading, but I just wrote `= ???` because I didn't know what the value of `tName` and `rCount` were after calling the constructor. Basically, that was my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you add `()` in `new non_t()`, members would be [value initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), so member will have value `0` in your case.

With `new non_t`, the members would be [default initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), so uninitialized in your case.

Adding constructor would avoid those subtleties.

```
struct s {
  s() : tName('\0'), rCount(0) {}

  char tName;
  int rCount;
};
```

or in c++11

```
struct s {
  char tName = '\0';
  int rCount = 0;
};
```

Comment: Oh.. so basically you're saying calling `non_t *s = new non_t()` would be wrong after already implementing it in the constructor? So to avoid that, just include a constructor in the struct?

Comment: I mean that, without appropriate constructor, the behavior between `new non_t` and `new non_t()` differs. With given constructor, both would initialize your members.

Comment: @Jarod42, simply not true. Your members will not be value-initialized. I am not sure who upvoted the post, but it certainly should not be accepted. This is a plain wrong answer.

Comment: @SergeyA: see [default_initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) and [value_initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) or I miss something ?

Comment: @Jarod42, yes, you do. Look at your own link: `if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized;` And than, on the default initialization page: `otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.`

Comment: @SergeyA: `"if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;"`. `s` has an **implicitly** default constructor.

Comment: @Jarod, actually, I fail to understand it. `with no default constructor` and `with a default constructor that is neither user-provided...` seem to be the same thing. Since unless deleted, default constructor will always be there, I understand 'with no default constructor' as 'with no user-provided default constructor'.

Comment: In both vc and clang, `s()` will value initialize and `s` will not. For some reason with gcc, everything is being default initialized to `0`.

Comment: @SergeyA: It states of the effect effects of *value initialization* (which might happen in other circumstance?). As `"with deleted default constructor"`, all provided form won't compile (also when default constructor is not generated when other constructors are provided).

Comment: @Jarod42, if you don't mind dummy editing your post, i will retract my incorrect downvote. Was really confused by the wording, which might've been clearer.

Comment: Upvoted ) i don't understand why i can't change my vote unless the answer was edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to be initialized to 0, you should do it in a constructor.  :)
Otherwise it'll be set to whatever random piece of memory it's allocated at.

```
struct s {
  s() : tName(' '), rCount(0) {}

  char tName;
  int rCount;
};
```

Comment: I thought of doing that, but isn't that only allowed in `C++11`? The `gcc` version I'm using doesn't support that

Comment: It's not a new feature -- structs are just like classes (except things are `public` by default)

Answer (score 2):

`int` and `char` cannot be `null`. The values will be undefined without a constructor that would initialize them.

```
struct s
{
  s() : rCount(0) {}
  char tName;
  int rCount;
};
```

This would initialize `rCount` to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `struct` works exactly like a `class` except all fields are `public` by default. You can make constructor that will initialize your struct with whatever default values you want.